# HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration. in solr.xml

Tags: .net, apache, solr, nutch

I am trying to install solr apache with solr nutch for web crawling, I am following a youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qs-18hRRpNU

Here is my path `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\solr\WEB-INF`, Where I installed the `solr.xml` file is as follows.

Below is the error for installing Solr Apache with Tomcat in Windows 10 did not know how to integrate Solr 6 with Solr Nutch so had to fall back on old Solr. Below is the error

```log
**HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration. 
Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong. 
If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change: 

<abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError> in solr.xml
-------------------------------------------------------------**
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory: 
C:\cygwin64\home\apache-solr-3.4.0\example\solr\.\data\index at 
org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initIndex(SolrCore.java:407) at
org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:552) at
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:463) at 
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:316) at 
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:207) at 
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.jav
a:130) at
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:94 at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:298) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:119) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4142) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4800) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:803) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:780) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583) at 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:944) at 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:779) at 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:505) at 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322) at 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325) at 
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1069) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:761) at 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289) at 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414) Caused by: java.io.IOException: 
Cannot create directory: C:\cygwin64\home\apache-solr-3.4.0\example\solr\.\data\index at 
org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLock.obtain(NativeFSLockFactory.java:171) at 
org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:72) at 
org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:1112) at 
org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:83) at 
org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initIndex(SolrCore.java:402) ... 32 more
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->

<web-app>

  <!-- Uncomment if you are trying to use a Resin version before 3.0.19.
    Their XML implementation isn't entirely compatible with Xerces.
    Below are the implementations to use with Sun's JVM.
  <system-property javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory=
             "com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl"/>
  <system-property javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=
             "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl"/>
  <system-property javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=
             "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl"/>
   -->

  <!-- People who want to hardcode their "Solr Home" directly into the
       WAR File can set the JNDI property here...
   -->
      <env-entry>
       <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
       <env-entry-value>C:\cygwin64\home\apache-solr-3.4.0\example\solr</env-entry-value>
       <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    </env-entry> 


  <!-- Any path (name) registered in solrconfig.xml will be sent to that filter -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>SolrRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter</filter-class>
    <!-- If you are wiring Solr into a larger web application which controls
         the web context root, you will probably want to mount Solr under
         a path prefix (app.war with /app/solr mounted into it, for example).
         You will need to put this prefix in front of the SolrDispatchFilter
         url-pattern mapping too (/solr/*), and also on any paths for
         legacy Solr servlet mappings you may be using.
         For the admin JSP's to work properly in a path-prefixed configuration,
         the admin folder containing the JSPs needs to be under the app context root
         named to match the path-prefix.  For example:

            .war
               xxx
                 admin
                   stats.jsp
    -->
    <!--
    <init-param>
      <param-name>path-prefix</param-name>
      <param-value>/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    -->
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <!--
      NOTE: When using multicore, /admin JSP URLs with a core specified
      such as /solr/coreName/admin/stats.jsp get forwarded by a
      RequestDispatcher to /solr/admin/stats.jsp with the specified core
      put into request scope keyed as "org.apache.solr.SolrCore".

      It is unnecessary, and potentially problematic, to have the SolrDispatchFilter
      configured to also filter on forwards.  Do not configure
      this dispatcher as <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>.
    -->
    <filter-name>SolrRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <!-- Otherwise it will continue to the old servlets -->

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SolrServer</servlet-name>
    <display-name>Solr</display-name>
    <description>Solr Server</description>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SolrUpdate</servlet-name>
    <display-name>SolrUpdate</display-name>
    <description>Solr Update Handler</description>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrUpdateServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Logging</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.LogLevelSelection</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <!-- @Deprecated -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ping</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/admin/ping.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SolrServer</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/select/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SolrUpdate</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/update/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Logging</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/logging</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- @Deprecated -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ping</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/ping</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- @Deprecated -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Logging</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/logging.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>.xsl</extension>
    <!-- per http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/PR-xslt20-20061121/ -->
    <mime-type>application/xslt+xml</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at exception it seems clear that your Solr instance cannot create the directory:

```
C:\cygwin64\home\apache-solr-3.4.0\example\solr\.\data\index
```

Be sure your user (or the user used to run Tomcat) have the right to create or write into the directory. You could create the directory before you run Solr and set correctly all the permissions.